# Subview above toolbar

Tags: iphone, ipad

I use [self setToolbarItems:items]; to add buttons to toolbar I want to display subview to be above all even teh toolbar I use the following code , but it be behind the tool bar

any suggestion how to make it above

```
 pickerView = [[UIPickerView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,744, 768, 216)];
        mytab = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 700, 768, 44)];


    pickerView.alpha=0.0;
    mytab.alpha=0.0;


    pickerView.showsSelectionIndicator = YES;
    pickerView.dataSource = self;
    pickerView.delegate = self;

    [self.view addSubview:pickerView];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:pickerView]; 


    mytab.tintColor=[UIColor blackColor];

    UIBarButtonItem * bt1=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemDone target:self action:@selector(_cancel)];
    UIBarButtonItem * flx=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];

    NSArray *arr=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:flx,bt1,nil];
    [mytab setItems:arr];
    [self.view addSubview:mytab];

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.3];
    pickerView.alpha=1.0;
    mytab.alpha=1.0;
    [UIView commitAnimations];


    [pickerView release];
    [mytab release];
    [bt1 release];
    [flx release];
    [arr release];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply subtract 44 from the Y of pickerview and toolbar

Answer (score 0):

you are adding the tool bar after the picker ... add the tool bar fist and then the picker...

actually i think you should be presenting the picker as a modal view controller's view..

EDIT:

You can see how a modal view controller is displayed in appple's sample codes. Look for `presentModalViewController` method

[SimpleEKDemo](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160)

[Metronome](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Metronome/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007434)

Comment: NO , I am not mentioning this toolbar , I main [self setToolbarItems:items] in another part of my code , I need the subview and  mytab to be above all , but it be below the toolbaritems

Comment: use presentModalViewController for presenting this view controller which contains the tab and the picker..

Comment: I am a newbie , could u give me more details